# Can an exponential distribution be shifted to have a nonzero mode?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

[image]It is very naive question, but I really get confused.
As I saw in some plots the maximum of the exponential distribution function the maximum is at a non zero parameter, as in the formula we have the $f(x)=\lambda\exp(-\lambda \cdot x)$. And the maximum should be at the point in which x=0, how in some distributions their maximum as at some other positive values of x. In the attached photo the distribution of the decay time of a scintillator(which is an exponential distribution)it has been demonstrated that it’s maximum value is NOT at time=0.

Comment: The exponential distribution does have a maximum at zero. What you are seeing is an initial rise and then exponential decay from a maximum.. If that does not help try editing more detail into your question.

Comment: Hi Kimia, welcome to this community! Sorry I have some problems understanding your question. What do you mean by "the probability density function explained by the exponential distribution function"? And I don't understand "how in some distributions their maximum as at some other positive values of x"... Is there some word missing?

Comment: @mdewey: the density of the exponential distribution is maximal at 0. kimia: are you looking for a shifted exponential distribution?

Comment: It should be something like $f(x)=\lambda\exp(-\lambda \cdot x) \mathbb{1}\{x\geq x_0\}$, where $x_0 > 0$ and $\mathbb{1}\{\cdot\}$ is the indicator function.

Comment: @Micheal, yes, thanks for the reply. I meant the shifted exponential.

Answer (score 2):

**The Exponential family of distributions is *special:*** the distribution suggested in your plot is equally (a) a *shifted Exponential* or (b) a *truncated Exponential.*

When $F$ is any (cumulative) distribution function, the transformation to the function

$$x \to F(x;\mu) = F(x-\mu)$$

literally shifts the entire graph of $F$ by $\mu$ units to the right.  On the other hand the *truncated* version of $F$, truncated to the region $[\mu,\infty),$ is the part of $F$ defined on the values $x\ge \mu,$ *renormalized to rise from $0$ at the left of $\mu$ to $1,$* as any distribution function must do.  Therefore the truncated function is

$$x \to \tilde F(x;\mu) = \frac{F(x) - F(\mu)}{1 - F(\mu)}\ \text{when}\ x \ge \mu\ \text{and}\ 0\ \text{otherwise.}$$

When these are the same function of $x,$ equating them and expressing the relation in terms of the survival function $S = 1-F,$ we find after simple algebra that when $x\ge \mu,$

$$S(x) = S(x-\mu)S(\mu)$$

**This is a defining property of an exponential function,** so if it is to hold generally (for arbitrary $\mu$), necessarily $S(x)$ is proportional to $e^{-\lambda x}$ for some positive number $\lambda$ whenever $x \ge 0.$  The density is proportional to

$$f(x) = -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}S(x)\ \propto\ \lambda e^{-\lambda x},$$

exactly as expressed in the question.  (Note that $f(x)\equiv 0$ for all negative $x$ when $f$ is an exponential density.)

*This gives us two different, but equivalent, ways to understand any exponentially decaying distribution tail.*

**The issue in the application** appears to be that the first few channels have not been measured.  Thus, *the graph shows a truncated distribution.*  In effect, its maximum (were it observable) indeed would occur at $x=0.$  Nevertheless, now that we have seen this distribution will be identical to a *shifted* exponential distribution and since (clearly) all standard exponential distributions have a peak density ("mode") at $0,$ the mode of this truncated/shifted distribution is found by shifting $0$ by $\mu$ units to the right.

Answer (score 0):

To extend my comment, what you can observe in the plot is something like a truncated exponential, of the form $f(x)=\lambda\exp(-\lambda \cdot (x-x_0)) \mathbb{1}\{x\geq x_0\}$, where $x_0 > 0$ and $\mathbb{1}\{\cdot\}$ is the indicator function.

This does not mean that it is a probability distribution since in order to be such must satisfy some properties $e.g. \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx =1$, and if you don't give more context it is difficult to say of what we are talking about.

Comment: I'd say that $f(x)=\lambda\exp(-\lambda(x-x_0))1\{x\ge x_0\}$ *is* a probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The *mode* of an exponential *distribution* is at 0; that's where the density function is the highest. The distribution stretches out to infinity and so has no maximum.

For a particular *sample* taken from an exponential distribution, the *modal bin* of a histogram of the sample will likely be the one nearest $0$ and the maximum of the sample will be the largest sample value. It is difficult to predict how big that may be.

Below are data summaries and histograms of three exponential samples, of sizes
20, 200, and 2000, respectively, taken from an exponential distribution with mean $\mu = 10$ (rate $\lambda = 0.1).$ [Sampling, computation, graphs from R.]

```
set.seed(704)
x1 = rexp(20, .1)
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2735  4.5809  8.1275  9.9434 13.6316 28.2281 
x2 = rexp(200, .1) 
summary(x2)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.04879  2.54700  6.94663  9.76887 13.43231 66.26606 
x3 = rexp(2000, .1)
summary(x3)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.00018  2.73615  6.62026  9.83479 13.53740 69.82752
```

Maximum values for the three samples are about 28.2, 66.3 and 69.8, respectively. The histogram of the smallest sample happens to have no unique modal bar. For the other two samples, the modal bar is adjacent to 0. The density curve of the population is shown in red on each histogram, its mode is at $0.$

[image]

The R code for making the figure is shown below:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(x1, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.1), xlim=c(0,70),
     col="skyblue2", main="n=20")
  curve(dexp(x, .1), add=T, col="red", lwd=2, n=10001)
 hist(x2, prob=T, br=20, ylim=c(0,.1), xlim=c(0,70), 
      col="skyblue2", main="n=200")
  curve(dexp(x, .1), add=T, col="red", lwd=2, n=10001)
 hist(x3, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.1), xlim=c(0,70),
     col="skyblue2", main="2000")
  curve(dexp(x, .1), add=T, col="red", lwd=2, n=10001)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```